# How to align Google ads in center?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress engine with story theme and have used Google Adsenses on my website. I want to align the 720x92 (responsive) ad in the center and there is no problem in the desktop version but in mobile version the ad is getting aligned with the contents instead of in the center of the page.

Is there any way to align the ad in center using CSS which do not follow the previously declared alignment codes.

I've tried following code--- but not working

```
<div style="display:block;margin: 0 auto 0 auto;">
{google ad code}
</div>
```

[image]
I want to align the blue rectangular selection in the center. In current state it is seems to be aligned in with the content which is default in the wordpress theme

Comment: Live example plzzz...

Comment: http://www.isrgrajan.com/articles/edu/rank-wise-bjmc-institutes-and-colleges-affiliated-to-ip-university/

Answer (score 4):

I found the following official solution:

```
<div align="center">
Ad Code
</div>
```

Learn more: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9190028

Comment: the align attribute is not available in React. How to achieve this with React?

Comment: I hope it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38367109/htmls-align-attribute-is-not-supported-in-reactjs

Comment: unfortunately not. `align` is not a supported property in `CSSProperties`.

Answer (score 1):

In your live link, the ad seem to occupy only `468 x 60`. Whereas, the amount of space you have given to display the ad is: `728 x 90`. So you need to change those dimensions:

```
width="728" height="90"
```

To match the ad:

```
width="468" height="60"
```

And then style it as:

```
display: block;
margin: auto;
width: 468px;
height: 60px;
```

To make it centrally displayed. You may need to adjust the margin accordingly!

Comment: Its responsive ad of Google and I've already defined following css codes for it 
`.adslot_1 { width: 320px; height: 100px; }
@media (min-width:500px) { .adslot_1 { width: 468px; height: 60px; } }
@media (min-width:800px) { .adslot_1 { width: 728px; height: 90px; } }`

Comment: Did you add the rules other than `width` and `height`? That's the main intention of the answer!

Comment: Yes I did as per Google recommendations.
Wait let me share the images

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use flexbox. Here is a sample with TailwindCSS:

```html
<div id="my-ad-slot-id" class="flex flex-row justify-center items-center" />
```

Here it is again in plain CSS:

```html
<div id="my-ad-slot-id" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: center; align-items: center;" />
```

Comment: for me it didn't work as width was not generating.