# Html's "align" attribute is not supported in ReactJS

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm new to ReactJS. In the react component, I've

```
    var SaveOrganization = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
    return (
        <div className="box-footer" align="center"> 
            <a href="addVenue" className="btn btn-info bottom-margin" >Add Venue</a>
            <a href="addCourt" className="btn btn-info bottom-margin" >Add Court</a>
            <a href="addPOI" className="btn btn-info bottom-margin" >Add POI</a>                    </div> 
    );
}})
```

But when I see the browser after rendering "align" attribute doesn't show up at all. Please help me on this.

Comment: [HTML 5 doesn't have an align attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#attributes-1). Use CSS instead.

Comment: I thought so! My mistake. Will correct the question to say just "html". But, would like to know was align attribute there from before or which version had it?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it seems that `align` is not supported by React.  [Here is the full list](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html).

I'd suggest using `style` (or css) instead:

```
return (
    <div className="box-footer" style={{textAlign:"center"}}> 
        <a href="addVenue" className="btn btn-info bottom-margin" >Add Venue</a>
        <a href="addCourt" className="btn btn-info bottom-margin" >Add Court</a>
        <a href="addPOI" className="btn btn-info bottom-margin" >Add POI</a>                    </div> 
);
```

Comment: @MamathaVRao you should accept his answer if it's truly perfect :)

Comment: i also think this has to do with the fact that `"align"` isn't supported in html5. Most browsers always try to be compatible so your old align tags would still work

Comment: align attribute and text-align styles are not same